# How to generate large seat layout with 1200 seats?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an app where i need to display a seat layout containing 900 to 1200 seats. I had managed to generate a 900 seat layout by creating LinearLayouts with customized TextViews programatically by looping. But I'm pretty sure that is definitely not the way to do it.

Here is what I was doing:

```
// Seat Layout
    LinearLayout linearLayoutSeatContainer;
    static final LinearLayout[] rows = new LinearLayout[30];
    static final TextView[][] seats = new TextView[30][30];
    static final View[][] spaceVertical = new View[30][4];
    static final View[] spaceHorizontal = new View[4];

// Populating the screen with seats
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        rows[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        rows[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // Each loop creates a row of seats
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {

            // To add horizontal space after every 10 seats
            if (j % 10 == 0) {
                spaceVertical[i][(j / 10)] = new View(this);
                spaceVertical[i][(j / 10)].setLayoutParams(spaceVerticalParams);
                rows[i].addView(spaceVertical[i][(j / 10)]);
            }

            seats[i][j] = new TextView(this);
            seats[i][j].setId(i * 100 + j);
            seats[i][j].setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
            seats[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seat_circle_empty);
            seats[i][j].setClickable(true);
            seats[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

            // TODO: Delete randomized code for disabled seats
            Random rand = new Random();
            int num = rand.nextInt(20);

            if (num % 5 == 0 && (i != 0 && j != 0))
                seats[i][j].setEnabled(false);

            rows[i].addView(seats[i][j]);
        }
        // Adding the last vertical space between screen and the last seat
        spaceVertical[i][3] = new View(this);
        spaceVertical[i][3].setLayoutParams(spaceVerticalParams);
        rows[i].addView(spaceVertical[i][3]);

        // To add horizontal space after every 10 rows of seats
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            spaceHorizontal[i / 10] = new View(this);
            spaceHorizontal[i / 10].setLayoutParams(spaceHorizontalParams);
            linearLayoutSeatContainer.addView(spaceHorizontal[i / 10]);
        }
        linearLayoutSeatContainer.addView(rows[i]);
    }

    // Adding the last horizontal space between screen and the last row
    spaceHorizontal[3] = new View(this);
    spaceHorizontal[3].setLayoutParams(spaceHorizontalParams);
    linearLayoutSeatContainer.addView(spaceHorizontal[3]);
```

Please ignore that bit with the randomization, that was for testing purposes. I know this is not the way of doing things. Please point me towards the right direction.

Comment: There is a useful library that you can look. https://github.com/captain-miao/SelectMovieSeat

Comment: why are you not using Grid layout?

Comment: one more that i found https://github.com/Nublo/HallScheme